# remove the warning of empty array if data is exist

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to remove the **warning** of **empty array** if data is exist.

If data is **empty**, the warning works.

But if data is exist and page is **refreshed**, the **warning** of **empty data** is showed, after that, the data showed

1. useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    retrieveFavourites();
}, []);
```

2. Display Favorite cats:

```
const [favourites, setFavourites] = useState([]);
  const retrieveFavourites = () => {
    TutorialDataService.getAllFav()
      .then((response) => {
        setFavourites(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };
```

3. Delete a cat:

```
const deleteCats = () => {
    TutorialDataService.remove(currentFavourite.id)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        alert("selesai unfavourite");
        window.location.reload();
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };
```

4. Display in web:

```
 {favourites.length === 0 ? (
            <p>belum ada yang ditambah</p>
          ) : (
            favourites &&
            favourites.map((favourite, index) => (
              <div
                class="col-md-3"
                key={index}
              >
                <div
                  class="card"
                  style={{
                    border: "2px solid",
                    borderColor: index === currentIndex ? "red" : null,
                  }}
                >
                  <img
                    src={favourite.image.url}
                    alt={favourite.image.id}
                    class="card-img-top"
                    width="100"
                    height="300"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            ))
          )}
```

Comment: What is the warning?

Comment: <p>belum ada yang ditambah</p>

Comment: add a loading state, and only show when loading is complete

Comment: can you show me the example? @FredStark

Answer (score 1):

When you refresh the page, the component re-renders.
`const [favourites, setFavourites] = useState([]);`,
`favourites` will always start as an empty array, then when your async call returns the data, then we set state. So the warning you see is as expected.

What you may want to do is add an intermediate loading boolean. For example
 `const [isLoading, setLoading] = React.useState(true)`

and in your jsx,

```
{
isLoading ? <LoadingIndicator/> : <FavouritesDisplay/>
}
```

Comment: where it must setLoading is placed?

Comment: add it above ``` const [favourites, setFavourites] ```,

Comment: I mean the setLoading, not the state

Comment: call `setLoading(false)` when you get the favourites in `getFavorites`

Comment: Hey @FebryAryo, did my answer help? if yes, could you help me out by selecting this as the correct answer? thanks

Comment: O. K., give me some to doing my other work, after that, I add a small detail to your answer as correct answer